Custom rhead with arrow hidden if rightmark is empty
I'm trying to make a custom pagestyle in which leftmark and rightmark are shown in the header alongside eachother. I want an arrow between them for aesthetic reasons, but I can't find a way to hide the arrow if rightmark is empty.
\documentclass[12pt, norsk, fleqn, leqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=0.6in,right=0.6in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in, heightrounded, headheight=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\title{Rapport - EP 02122024-1}

\fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \newgeometry{left=0.6in, right=0.6in, top=0.2in, bottom=0.2in, heightrounded, headheight=2.5cm, includeheadfoot}
    %\setlength\headheight{2.5cm}
    \lhead{
        \strut
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1.5cm}
            \vspace{0pt}
            %\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,valign=t]{../../MT-logo_2015.eps}
        \end{minipage}
    }

    \rhead{
        \strut
        \hfill\strut\begin{minipage}[t]{16cm}
            \vspace{0pt}
            \hfill{\bfseries Test of Minimal Working Environment}

            \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
            
            % Include the section number and name
            \hfill\leftmark\ \ $\rightarrow$ \ \rightmark

            \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}

            \hfill Side \thepage\ av \pageref{LastPage}
        \end{minipage}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{normal}

\section{MWE}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

I've tried various alternatives to acheive this. For instance:
% Conditional display of arrow and subsection title
\hfill\leftmark\ \ 
\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifx\rightmark\empty} }
    {} % Do nothing if \rightmark is empty
    {%
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\baselineskip,valign=t]{../../section_arrow.eps}\ \rightmark
    }

And this:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checksubsection}{
    \ifx\@empty\rightmark
        % Do nothing
    \else
        \includegraphics[height=0.6\baselineskip,valign=t]{../../section_arrow.eps}\ \rightmark
    \fi
}
\makeatother

But I'm stuck... Does anyone have an idea as to how to acheive this if it is possible?
06.12.2024 - Edited as to include a minimal working environment.
